# Variable in the shared and managed memory in cuda

Tags: cuda, fortran, gpu, gpu-shared-memory, gpu-managed-memory

With the unified memory feature now in CUDA, variables can be in the `managed` memory and this makes the code a little simpler. Whereas the `shared` memory is shared between threads in a thread block. See section 3.2 in [CUDA Fortran.](http://www.pgroup.com/doc/pgicudaforug.pdf)

My question is can a variable be in both the `shared` and `managed` memory? They would be `managed` in the host but on the device, they would be `shared`What type of behaviour maybe expected of this type of variable ?

I am using CUDA Fortran. I ask this question because, declaring the variable as `managed` makes it easier for me to code whereas making it `shared` in the device makes it faster than the global device memory.

I could not find anything that gave me a definitive answer in the documentation.

Comment: There is no such thing as "declaring" variables as managed or pinned in CUDA.

Comment: I think there is: [doc](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-unified-memory-programming-hd) Quote" Finally, language integration allows direct reference of a GPU-declared __managed__ variable and simplifies a program further when global variables are used.


"

Comment: Right that is for *GPU* declared variables, to map them into the managed address space. But that isn't what you are asking about. Pinned/page locked memory is host memory, and you question is about host memory, and there are is no declaration syntax there. Whether host memory is managed or pinned  depends on which API you used to allocate them.

Comment: Sorry, I had got confused between the shared memory and the pinned memory. I have edited the question now.

Comment: You never mentioned anywhere in the question that you were talking about CUDA Fortrain

Comment: There was no CUDA fortran tag available. And I did not have privileges to create tags. I should have mentioned it in the question, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is can a variable be in both the shared and managed memory?

No, it's not possible.

Managed memory is [created](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-explicit-allocation) with either a static allocator (`__managed__` in CUDA C, or `managed` attribute in CUDA fortran) or a dynamic allocator (`cudaMallocManaged` in CUDA C, or `managed` (allocatable) attribute in CUDA fortran).

Both of these are associated with the logical **global** memory space in CUDA.  The `__shared__` (or `shared`) memory space is a separate logical space, and must be used (allocated, accessed) explicitly, independent of any **global** space usage.